# Creating datasource for nested object in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I am trying my hands on Angular for a project and I am stuck with creating a data source for my MatTable.

The API that I am consuming sends response like this:

```
{
    data: [], //array of objects for samples
    total: 100, //total number of samples found
    pageSize: 10,
    pageIndex: 0
}
```

My model for samples is:

```
//Model for a single sample
export class Sample {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

//a plural namespace is used for multiple samples returned from API
export class Samples {
    samples: Sample[],
    total: number;
    pageSize: number;
    pageIndex: number;
}

// a const in case no samples were found
export const NO_SAMPLES {
    total: 0,
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 0,
    samples: []
}
```

Now when I am trying to integrated this with a data source like below:

```
... //required imports
export class SamplesDataSource extends DataSource<Samples> {

private samplesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Samples>(NO_SAMPLES);

public constructor(private samplesService: SamplesService) {
    super();
}

//this is where the error (described below) is showing
connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Samples> {
    return this.samplesSubject.asObservable();
}

disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    this.samplesSubject.complete();
}

getSamples() {
    this.samplesService.getSamples().pipe(
        catchError(err => {
            return of([]);
        })
    ).subscribe(
        samples => this.samplesSubject.next(samples)
    );

}

}
```

But it shows me error message:

> ERROR in src/app/shared/data-sources/samples-data-source.ts(20,5): error TS2416: Property 'connect' in type 'SamplesDataSource' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'DataSource'

How can I handle this case.

Please note, I need to retain `total`, `pageSize` and `pageIndex` for my paginator to work in align with the paginator at backend.

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

App component.ts

```
    ... //required imports
export class AlertCasesComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  samplesTableColumns: string[] = ['sampleId', 'sample'];
  samplesTablePageSizes: number[] = [10, 20, 50, 100];
  samplesDataSource: SamplesDataSource;

  ...

  constructor(samplesService: SamplesService) {
    ...
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.samplesDataSource = new SamplesDataSource(this.samplesService);
      this.samplesDataSource.getSamples();
      ...
  }

  ...

}
```

App Component.html

```
<mat-table class="..." [dataSource]="samplesDataSource.samples">

    .... //rows and columns implementations

</mat-table>

<mat-paginator [length]="samplesDataSource.total" pageIndex="0" [pageSize]="samplesDataSource.pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="samplesTablePageSizes" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Please provide a Stackblitz example.

Comment: Could you add more sources to demonstrate how `total/pageSize/pageIndex` properties are used? I answered about the error, but I didn't understand how you use these properties.

Comment: you do not need to extend data source, just make it like this  `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();`

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov These fields will be used to control the paginator as the responses will be paginated and/or filtered.

Comment: @NavruzbekNoraliev I will try that and share if that solves the problem. Incase I am not extending, how can I use the connect and disconnect features of the datasource. Can you share some example of such implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `DataSource.connect()` [should return](https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview#connecting-the-table-to-a-data-source) an observable that emits an array of data. So, the SamplesDataSource should return array of samples, like:

```js
export class SamplesDataSource extends DataSource<Sample> {
  private samplesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Samples>(NO_SAMPLES);

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Sample[]> {
    return this.samplesSubject.asObservable().pipe(
      map(samples => samples.samples)
    );
  }

  ...
}
```

[Here is](https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview) the official CDK table example, I hope it will help you. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nldardyrdqq?file=app%2Fcdk-table-basic-example.ts) version is also available.

#### Update:

It isn't necessary to use `DataSource` class in your case, you can use an array of samples as the data source. I've created the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upcnrt).

**table-basic-example.ts**

```js
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';

export interface Sample {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface Samples {
  samples: Sample[];
  total: number;
  pageSize: number;
  pageIndex: number;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Sample[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Boron'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Carbon'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Nitrogen'},
  {id: 8, name: 'Oxygen'},
  {id: 9, name: 'Fluorine'},
  {id: 10, name: 'Neon'}
];

@Injectable()
export class SamplesService {
  getSamples(pageIndex: number, pageSize: number): Observable<Samples> {
    const start = pageIndex * pageSize;
    const samples = ELEMENT_DATA.slice(start, start + pageSize);
    return of<Samples>({
      samples: samples,
      pageIndex: pageIndex,
      pageSize: pageSize,
      total: ELEMENT_DATA.length
    }).pipe(
      delay(500)
    );
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  providers: [ SamplesService ]
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  readonly displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name'];
  readonly page$ = new BehaviorSubject({
    index: 0,
    size: 4
  });

  samples: Samples = {
    total: 0,
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 0,
    samples: []
  };

  constructor(
    private readonly samplesService: SamplesService
  ) {
    this.page$.pipe(
      switchMap(page => {
          return this.samplesService.getSamples(page.index, page.size);
      })
    ).subscribe(samples => {
      this.samples = samples;
    });
  }

  onPageChanged(event: PageEvent) {
    this.page$.next({
      index: event.pageIndex,
      size: event.pageSize
    });
  }
}
```

**table-basic-example.html**

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="samples.samples" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator
  [length]="samples.total"
  pageIndex="pageIndex$.value"
  [pageSize]="samples.pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[4, 9]"
  showFirstLastButtons
  (page)="onPageChanged($event)"></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: In the `connect` function you are returning an observable of array of `Sample[]`, but my actual response will not contain an array of sample but a single response of type `Samples`. The interface of which is defined in the question.

Comment: The stckblitz example also uses a simple object of `ELEMENT_DATA`, but the data I am dealing here is actually a wrapper object, say, `ELEMENTS_DATA` with `ELEMENT_DATA` as one of its property/field.

Comment: @pkimtani The DataSource is designed to return an observable that emits an array of rows data and it cannot emit anything else. The question is not about how to force the DataSource to emit the Samples instance, the question is about how you intend to use the `Samples` class. If you want to implement pagination, take a look at [MatTableDataSource](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource). If you still want to use your `Samples`, please add a code sample, which uses this class, because it's hard to understand how it's going to be used.

Comment: Yes, I know it can only emit an array of data, but I want to emit object instead. I have updated my question with the component implementation part, if that's what you were asking.

Comment: @pkimtani Thanks, It isn't necessary to use the `DataSource` class in your case. I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: @ Valeriy Thanks for the solution, it seems to work, though it opened up a new issue for me, but that is beyond the scope of this question so I will mark it as accepted. Thanks again for giving it your time and helping me out. Cheers